# fullcalendar working with qtip2.1.1

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, qtip2

Upgrading qtip for fullcalendar
I thought it would be a matter of just resetting the js call. Nope.

Can anyone confirm that they have fullcalendar 1.5.4 working with qtip 2.1.1???

There is a fiddle on the qtip site but the syntax is way different than the eventRender example in the fullcal documentation. Upgrading to fullcal 1.6 is an obvious move but I doubt this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The last fullcalendar works for the lasted qtooltip:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) { 
    var text = '<p>Start: '+event.start+'<br/>End: '+event.end+'</p>';
    element.qtip({ content: text});
}
```